# IIS Web Farm No owin.Environment item was found in the context

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis, owin

I am trying to set load balancing with IIS ARR but getting this error when I try to login, It works find if I test it outside ARR

Server Error in '/' Application. No owin.Environment item was found in the context. Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: No owin.Environment item was found in the context.

Source Error:

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:
After lots and lots of investigation and googling for answer, I still did not find answer why that error was happening. At last I tried fresh project and moved all my files to it and it worked.

It must have been some settings or anything, I don't know really. but creating new solution solved it.

if anyone knows exact reason why this happen, I would still like to know this.

Comment: I have tried all possible solution after spending 2 days but no luck. It works fine on local and IIS but does not work with ARR IIS load balancing.

Comment: @Eilon any help on this please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After lots and lots of investigation and googling for answer, I still did not find answer why that error was happening. At last I tried fresh project and moved all my files to it and it worked.

It must have been some settings or anything, I don't know really. but creating new solution solved it.

if anyone knows exact reason why this happen, I would still like to know this.